# SVN hook to check a change was also made to the corresponding Test class

Tags: svn, unit-testing, tdd, hook

Has anyone come across an SVN pre-commit hook that works with the following logic?

If "MyClass.java" has been modified and is being committed, then there must also be a modification to "MyClassTest.java", by naming convention.

The goal here is to make sure that a developer made changes to the corresponding unit test, when s/he changed a piece of code.

I know this can be cheated by simply changing a little bit of formatting. But the goal is not to stop cheating. It is to very strongly encourage test driven development in a team that is moving to it.

A bonus would be, for when the change is just a refactor, for the hook to ignore the check if the submit comment has the word "REFACTOR". (after all pure refactors should always be committed by themselves)

Comment: That seems a bit restrictive. What if you are just refactoring the code and don't need a new test? Or what if you are just adding a test?

Comment: Adding a new test should not matter. As for refactoring, perhaps there should be an override - example: if the commit comment contains the word "REFACTOR" then do not do the test check

Comment: To add to what @Alexandre said, what if you modify an interface? Do you have an <Interface>Test.java test? It seems overkill to make a test for an interface just to satisfy the SVN commit hook.  We use TDD a lot, and often when we refactor code which already has a bunch of tests, we can refactor without fear because the code is already 100% unit tested. Why should I be forced to make a change to the test, the tests already cover 100% of the code...

Comment: As for refactors, you can clearly label the commit message as REFACTOR, and the hook will ignore it. As for interfaces, you can do a similar thing with a label. I think the need for discipline in my case out weighs the minor work around for these cases. How else can I enforce Unit Tests?

Comment: @Patrick I still think this kind of automated process enforcement is too restrictive. What if you need to fix an incorrect docstring or a typo on the UI. The devs may get in the habit to use the REFACTOR message for every little change that doesn't require an unit test. Perhaps code reviews would be more effective in this case.

Comment: It's finding a balance between a too restrictive hook and a subtle way to have discipline with unit tests.

Comment: I agree with @Alexandre here. Brute force is a recipe for passive aggressive resistance. It's very easy to cheat the SVN hook. I could simply reformat a test case and commit it or add tests that don't really add value just so that I can meet the criteria for the commit. I think that there are other approaches to solving this problem that use influence rather than carrots and sticks. If you're interested in some options let me know.

Comment: @bcarlso — That sounds like a valid premise for an answer, even if it doesn't directly apply to commit hooks.  Sometimes the best answer to a question is to suggest that the question itself is the wrong one to ask.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is an "enforcement" of unit testing, I suggest checking in the post-commit (test do run slower than the usual commit operation) if the test coverage decreased for any class. even more, put that check in your Continuous Integration server.

Of course, this may lead to "stupid" test of get and set just to get more coverage. This can be "prevented" by assigning a coverage threshold and alert only if the threshold is reached.

This way you can sell the team the idea of a "mechanism to alert us if we make a mistake" instead of "a mechanism to punish you if you do wrong".

Comment: Thanks Soronthar. This is the right way to go. Having CI monitoring progress of coverage.